# How can I solve an equation with symbolic coefficients?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to try to solve the following

```
 a x^(17/6) - b x^2 - 1 == 0
```

where `a` and `b` are variable coefficients (which are very small and positive).

I cannot get an analytic solution (not surprised), but `NSolve` is not doing the job for me. I am a novice to Mathematica; is anyone able to do `NSolve` for `x` on Mathematica and get a numerical result?

Comment: By `Solve` *Mathematica* returns a `Root` object, which **indeed** an analytical solution, as I know. And stated [in documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html).

Comment: You´ll only get numerical solutions if you provide values for `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 5):

One thing that you could do is to rescale your equation:

```
Clear[x, ξ, eq1, eq2, A];
eq1 = a x^(17/6) - b x^2 - 1 == 0
eq1 /. x -> A*ξ // PowerExpand
```

The result is:

> -1 - A^2 b ξ^2 + a A^(17/6) ξ^(17/6) == 0

Choose A such that the factor in front of the largest power is unity:

```
s1 = Solve[a A^(17/6) == 1, A][[1, 1]];
Simplify[(eq1 /. x -> A*ξ /. s1) /. b -> c*a^(12/17), {A > 0, a > 0, b > 0}]
```

where `c = b/a^(12/17)`. Now you have an equation with a single parameter, easy to solve. Here it is:

```
1 + c ξ^2 == ξ^(17/6)
```

You can define the interval of its variation, I cannot do that. For this reason to give an example I suppose that c varies from 0 to 2. Let us look at the solution. Evaluate this:

```
Plot[{1 + \[Xi]^2, ξ^(17/6)}, {ξ, 0, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["\[Xi]"], 
     Row[{Style["1+\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Xi]\), \(2\)]\), ", Red], 
     Style["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Xi]\), \(17/16\)]\)", Blue]}]}]
```

You will see this image: [image: The image shows the intersection of the left- and right-hand parts of the equation in question]![enter image description here]

There is a solution in the vicinity of `ksi`=`1.5`. Now we can make a list of numeric solutions of this equation. Evaluate this:

```
lst = Table[{c, FindRoot[1 + c*ξ^2 == ξ^(17/6), {ξ, 1.4}][[1, 2]]}, {c, 0.1, 2, 0.01}];
```

By plotting this list, one finds the dependence of solutions upon the value of the parameter c. Evaluating this:

```
ListPlot[Select[lst, #[[2]] ∈ Reals &], 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["c", 14], Style["ξ", 14]}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

One gets the following plot: [image: Dependence of the solutions ksi upon the parameter c]![Dependence of the solution ksi upon the parameter c]![enter image description here]![enter image description here]

This is already the solution you are looking for. You can do somewhat more, however. If one fits the solution by some simple function on this interval of c, one finds (though approximate) an analytical and accurate solution that can be used in further analytical calculations, if any:

```
ft = Fit[Select[lst, #[[2]] ∈ Reals &], {1, c, c^2}, c]
```

which yields this:

```
1.00914 + 0.292415 c + 0.231262 c^2
```

This is your solution. To see, how accurate it is, evaluate this:

```
Show[{
   ListPlot[Select[lst, #[[2]] ∈ Reals &], 
      AxesLabel -> {Style["c", 14], Style["\[Xi]", 14]}],
   Plot[ft, {c, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red]
}]
```

You will obtain the following plot:

[image]

Have fun.

Comment: Would you consider replacing the fancy typesetting like `\[Xi]` with simpler symbols to make browsing your code on-site easier?

Answer (score 3):

Geometrically, the locus of $(x,y)$ for which $a x - b y - 1 = 0$ is a line orthogonal to the vector $(a, -b)$, because the equation can be written $(a,-b)\cdot (x,y)=1$.  This invites us to pose the problem as a geometric intersection:

> Find all points of intersection of the line $a x - b y - 1 = 0$ and the curve $t\to (t^{17/6}, t^2)$.

Because this curve (clearly) is an arc starting at $(0,0)$ and rising at a rate of $O(x^{12/17}) \lt O(x)$ and the line (also clearly) has positive slope and negative intercept when $a\gt 0$ and $b\gt 0$, it is geometrically evident that a *unique* point of intersection exists.  If you're unconvinced, or just want to appreciate the solutions a little better, you may use `Manipulate` to explore the situation in terms of $a$ and $b$.  `ContourPlot` is good for showing functions given in implicit form (like $a x - b y - 1 == 0$) and `ParametericPlot` is good for plotting parameterized curves.  Thus:

```
h[a_, b_] := Block[{x}, x /. FindRoot[a x^(17/6) - b x^2 - 1 == 0, {x, 10^12}]];
Manipulate[
 u =  h[a, b];
 Show[
  ContourPlot[a x - b y, {x, 0, 200000}, {y, -10, 5000}, Contours -> {1}],
  ParametricPlot[{t^(17/6), t^2}, {t, 0, 300}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
  Epilog -> {White, PointSize[0.015], Point[{u^(17/6), u^2}]}],
 {a, 10^-6, 1}, {b, 10^-6, 1}
 ]
```

[image: Plot]

(`FindRoot` works just fine to obtain a numerical solution--shown as a white dot--provided we ask it to start near infinity in its search.)

Now that we know there is a unique solution, use `Solve` to obtain an analytic expression.  Let's encapsulate this in a function of the variable coefficients:

```
f[a_, b_] := Evaluate[Flatten[x /. Solve[a x^(17/6) - b x^2 - 1 == 0, {x}]]]
```

This function returns a list of $17$ `Root` objects; for instance, the first in the list is

$$\text{Root}\left[-1-6 b \text{$\#$1}^2-15 b^2 \text{$\#$1}^4-20 b^3 \text{$\#$1}^6-15 b^4 \text{$\#$1}^8-6 b^5 \text{$\#$1}^{10}-b^6 \text{$\#$1}^{12}+a^6 \text{$\#$1}^{17}\&,1\right].$$

This is a perfectly good "analytic" expression.  Moreover, because `Solve` guarantees that it will list its real roots first, this is the unique real root (when $a\gt 0$ and $b \gt 0$).  We can plot it as a function of the coefficients $a$ and $b$ (although it takes some time--around a minute):

```
ContourPlot[f[a, b][[1]], {a, 0, .1}, {b, 0, .1}]
```

[image: Plot of first root]

(As a check, a plot of the numeric solution `h[a,b]` looks the same.)

Yes, our eyes do not deceive us: the contours are truly parts of lines.  The same geometric reasoning shows that for any given $x$, the set of $(a,b)$ for which $x$ is a solution lies on a line orthogonal to $(x^{17/6}, -x^2)$.